# How do registers quickly store and retrieve data on a context switch?

Tags: cpu-registers

Registers are the fastest type of memory. On a context switch, registers have to save their data somewhere and then they have to load the right data into the registers for that particular context. This could be a slow process if the registers aren't storing and retrieving their data from other registers.

But I'm not sure what registers use to store and retrieve data for context switches. I don't think they use other registers. What do they use?

Also, about how often does a context switch take place?

Comment: Depends upon architecture, at the very least.

Comment: You have a basic misassumption in "quickly". Context switching is anything but.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of googling yields this fairly in-depth wiki [article on context switching](http://wiki.osdev.org/Context_Switching).

How often this happens depends on the operating system; on Linux, it depends on what scheduler algorithm is in fashion this week, and what parameters it's been compiled with.

Comment: That article says that it saves the information to a TSS. What is that in hardware? Is that a register?

Comment: The phrase "TSS" in the article is hotlinked to another page. You can click through to learn more about the TSS.

Comment: @z-buffer That's the name of the data structure representing the "context". The name "segment" implies it's stored in the memory.

Comment: @z-buffer Obviously there's nothing preventing you from saving the register state into other registers, except that CPUs don't really tend to have spare register memory to store a copy of the "normal" registers for every running process.

Comment: @z-buffer The linked article also explicitly mentions pushing register values on the *stack* (which is in memory) for the software context switching method they describe.